# Choppy video even with 'Lossless' settings?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm using Blender 2.82's Video Editing pane to create a video from a series of images (also generated in Blender).

No matter what settings I use, I am unable to create a consistently fluid video. Although some sections are smooth, there will always be bits that are choppy (seemingly at random times).

Image sequence:

- 5000 images
- PNG format, generated by Blender
- Dimensions: 1920 x 1080
- Size: ~3.68 MB each
- Bit depth 25
- Compression: 15%

Output settings:

- Frame Rate: 24 fps
- File Format: FFmpeg video
- Container: Matroska
- Video Codec: H.264
- Output quality: Perceptually lossless
- Encoding Speed: Slowest

What's more, despite the choppiness, the output file is huge (2 GB for a 3:22 minute video).

Any advice on generating a smooth video? What would be an expected file size? Thanks.

Comment: Does the image sequence look correct in the preview before exporting? Or if you use encode the image sequence directly to video with ffmpeg? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg https://superuser.com/questions/624567/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-using-ffmpeg#12160155